# RESTFul web service URL style

Tags: web-services, web

Is the difference between having url parameters passed as

```
http://myserver/someoperation/bob/sally
```

versus

```
http://myserver/someoperation?arg1=bob&arg2=sally
```

purely up to user preference or are there good reasons for each?

I have a web service that is using the first style, but I am wondering if I am missing part of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as search engine optimization goes, Google has stated:

> If your URL contains relevant words, this provides users and search engines with more information about the page than an ID or oddly named parameter would.

That seems to imply that having pages where your URLs have meaningful information would give your page a better ranking although they don't outright say that.

You can read more on their full guide: [Google Search Engine Optimization Starter Guide](http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf) (PDF).  That quote was from page 8.